# PHP json_encode and json_decode

Tags: php

I have the code below as a response from PHP API:

```
$response = array(
     'status' => 'hi',
      'link' => 'bye'
);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($response);
```

I want to store the value of 'status'. so I'm doing the below:

```
$json = json_decode($response->body(),true);
$status = $json['status'];
dd($json);
```

but I get this error as result:
**Trying to access array offset on value of type null**
how can I solve it?

Comment: What’s the value of `$response->body()`? `$json` seems to be `null`.

Comment: dd($response->body());  is  {"status":"hi","link":"bye"}

Comment: `$response` is an array, why would it have a `body()` method?

Comment: If `json_decode($response->body(), true);` fails, you can check what [`json_last_error_msg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) has to say.

Answer (score 1):

use it that way.

```
$response = array(
    'status' => 'hi',
    'link' => 'bye'
);
$json = json_encode($response);
```

---

```
$json = json_decode($json,true);
$status = $json['status'];
print_r($status);
```

**body()** is not a method.

**echo json_encode($response);** is only a json **TEXT**